# Difference in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I want to know how is my query different than the solution. In my opinion, My query is also right but seems like there are some differences in the values. Any help would be appreciated which could help me to
get better in the understanding.

Question:

```
Write a query to return the percentage of revenue for each of the following films: film_id <= 10.
Formula: revenue (film_id x) * 100.0/ revenue of all movies.
```

My query:

```sql
select film_id, revenue*100/sum(revenue) over() as revenue_percentage
from
(
  select i.film_id,sum(p.amount) as revenue
  from inventory i 
  join rental r on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
  join payment p on p.rental_id = r.rental_id
  group by i.film_id
) x
where film_id <=10
order by film_id;
```

Recommended solution:

```sql
WITH movie_revenue AS (
    SELECT 
        I.film_id, SUM(P.amount) revenue
    FROM payment P
    INNER JOIN rental R
    ON R.rental_id = P.rental_id
    INNER JOIN inventory I
    ON I.inventory_id = R.inventory_id
    GROUP BY I.film_id
)
select * from movie_revenue;
SELECT film_id, revenue * 100.0 / SUM(revenue) OVER() revenue_percentage
FROM movie_revenue
ORDER BY film_id
LIMIT 10;
```

In my understanding, I am also doing the same thing in the nested query which will execute first and then
doing the final select along with window function.

Comment: These queries are absolutely equivalent in MySQL. In PostgreSQL (maybe except the most recent version) your query will be faster because of CTE matherialization in "recommended" solution. PS. The row `select * from movie_revenue;` in recommended solution must be removed or commented.

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolved it. My solution or the logic of nested query is right. Earlier, I was worried about the order in which the nested block is created might have caused the error.
However, the mistake is that I am using where clause which limits the data which causes window function to run on that subset only.
Once, I removed that and placed limit 10 after the order by clause. My solution worked same as recommended solution.

Comment: *Once, I removed that and placed limit 10 after the order by clause.* This does not match the question where the condition is specified explicitly as `film_id <= 10` (not "10 least film_id values") rather than `LIMIT 10` which does not provide this condition.

Comment: @Akina it already has order by statement and the values does start from 1. But you are right if the values doesn't start from 1 then there has to be a where clause. What could be the solution in that general case?

Comment: *and the values does start from 1* This may change, is it? delete any row with film_id from 1 to 10 - and "recommended" solution will give wrong output. *What could be the solution in that general case?* Your solution, with explicit `where film_id <=10`, is correct, recommended one is really wrong.

Comment: @akina thanks for clarifying. But I am wondering in my logic, would the window function work as expected? I'm new to window function

Comment: Why not? I do not see the source of your doubt.